# Как правильно расположить элементы внутри флекс-контейнера и задать им размер?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно, без костылей, расположить элементы внутри флекс=контейнера.

Без margin'ов у меня не получается раскидать элементы по их местам... Но ведь же безкостыльное решение этой проблемы, да?

[Выглядеть все должно, как здесь:](https://vassiliymarkov.github.io/mevents/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(347px + (370 - 347) * ((87.32vh - 533px) / (631 - 533)));
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(160px + (300 - 160) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1800 - 320)));
  height: calc(300px + (365 - 300) * ((87.321711569vh - 533px) / (631 - 533)));
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-family: 'Jaapokki-regular', serif;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease-out;
}

.container.show {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.rectangle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.logoWraper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  object-fit: cover;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.logoRectangle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 155px;
  width: 103%;
}

.login a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
    <div class="logoWraper"><img class="logoRectangle" src="img/logo/logo_trans.png" alt="logo"></div>
    <span>TOUT POUR VOTRE EVENEMENT</span>
  </div>
  <div class="login">
    <a href="#">CLIENTS</a>
    <a href="#">PRESTATAIRES</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Почитай классное руководство по флексам https://habr.com/ru/articles/467049/ . С размерами уже сам разберешься

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: end;
  background: url(./1.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-family: 'Jaapokki-regular', serif;
}

.rectangle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.logoWraper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  object-fit: cover;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.logoRectangle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.login a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 5px solid white;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
    <div class="logoWraper"><img class="logoRectangle" src="img/logo/logo_trans.png" alt="logo"></div>
    <span>TOUT POUR VOTRE EVENEMENT</span>
  </div>
  <div class="login">
    <a href="#">CLIENTS</a>
    <a href="#">PRESTATAIRES</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .Добрый день, спасибо, руководство обязательно изучу. Предложенное вами решение все выравнивает, но блок встает ниже того места, где он должен быть. У меня там немножко замороченный первый экран но постараюсь найти  решение. Спасибо!

Comment: тут просто очень умные админы любят чужой код менять без объяснения. Мой изначальный код выставил блоки так как в примере) Советую на сайте "примере"  жать f12 и исследовать по блокам размеры и параметры

Comment: нет, нет, блоки стоят, как надо :) просто сам весь блок с твоим кодом встал намного ниже, чем должен был. я чуть поменял код, но пока не удалось выставить его , как надо - ровно по центру экрана за минусом высоты хедера (надеюсь, я понятно объясняю). я новичек в разработке